# Waiting for completion of parallel running shell scripts

Tags: shell

I have an array and using that array I need to run the shell scripts in parallel as

```
for i in arr 
do
sh i.sh &
done

wait
```

I need to wait for the completion of their execution before proceeding to the next step.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: the script is not waiting for the execution of the commands inside for loop

Comment: Maybe you are running some mad shell? You should consider using a shebang at the start so your intentions and assumptions are clear to the computer and readers alike.

Comment: Is there any fork in any of the `i.sh` scripts?

Comment: You may also want to look into this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305078/137538).

Comment: `for i in "${arr[@]}"` presumably?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your script doesn't do what you want it to do for a different reason than you're expecting. `sh i.sh &` is trying to run a file called `i.sh`. It's not using the variable `i`. To fix it, simply add `$` before the `i`. it is waiting for commands to complete. Just not the ones you're expecting it to. It's actually trying to run the same script that doesn't exist a bunch of times.

```
for i in arr 
do
    sh $i.sh &
done

wait
```